# ruby-on-rails devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Ruby On Rails and devise gem.

I want redirect user after registration, but in devise i can redirect only after sign_in (http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this wiki page](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile), but instead of defining `after_update_path_for` define `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for`.

See the original [registrations_controller](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) for more information and methods.